# Desktop Access to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was wondering if there was a desktop application that I can sync my phpMyAdmin Database or multiple databases with. I want to be able to access my databases from my desktop as apposed to to logging into my hosting service again and again. Insert, Update, Delete, Create Tables Ect. 
Any Suggestions?

Comment: This question is too broad.  What do you mean by "sync?"

Comment: I don't think its that broad I want to be able to view, edit, delete etc. from my own computer and not have to constantly log in through my hosting company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dektop client for mysql. You just need the connection details for your database (host/ip, username, password).

The client is officially provided by MySQL and you can do everything with it you can do through phpMyAdmin.

Here is the link: [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)